# Debugging JavaScript in embedded V8 engine

Tags: javascript, c++, debugging, v8

I'm integrating V8 JavaScript engine inside my C++ application. What are the current options to debug JavaScript code executed inside V8 engine?

I would like to use Visual Studio Code with chrome-debug extension https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug but can't figure out how to enable remote debugging inside V8 engine?

PS: In V8's embedder guide https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Debugging%20Protocol I can see message debug protocol for out-of-process debugging is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because vscode-chrome-debug support Node.js debugging  I decided to use node.js debug-agent code to expose TCP port (5858 by default) for V8 debug protocol https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/debug-agent.cc

Comment: Was it difficult to integrate with a standalone non-node app?

Comment: Not really. We just take node, turn project artifact to dll library add javascript entry  point via function called from main app. You can look at our efforts here: https://github.com/BazisSoft/node-delphi. Feel free to ask Let0s for assistance.